Collected Django form data isn't displayed in the target URL which contains the HTML view
I created a Django form that asks the user to enter his order to display it in other page, but when I click on submit button it redirects me to the the URL I want without displaying the data the user entered in the form.
This is the view.py code:
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms 

# Create your views here.

orders_stock = ['headphones', 'earbuds', 'diy tools']



class NewOrder(forms.Form):
    get_order = forms.CharField(label='Your order', max_length=50)


def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = NewOrder(request.POST)
        if item.is_valid():
            get_order = item.cleaned_data['get_order']
            orders_stock.append(get_order)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('form/orders.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'form/form.html', {
                'items': orders_stock
            })

    return render(request, 'form/form.html', {
        'form': NewOrder()
    })


def order(request):
    return render(request, 'form/orders.html', {
        'items': orders_stock,
    })

This is the form.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Form submission</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'formsubmit:order'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


And this is the orders.html code which handle the added orders display:
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Orders</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Orders</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for order in items %}
            <li>{{order}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

And this is the urls.py code :
from . import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'formsubmit'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.form, name='form'),
    path('order', views.order, name='order')
]

I've tried many solutions but nothing seems to work appropriately.

Your code has a few issues that are preventing it from working as expected. Here's the modification needed.
1. Redirect to the Correct URL: When the form is successfully submitted, the HttpResponseRedirect should redirect to the order view. However, the URL in your code, form/orders.html, is not a URL name. Instead, use HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('formsubmit:order')).
2. Form Action in form.html Template: In your HTML template, the action="{% url 'formsubmit:order' %}" URL points to the order display page, while it should actually point to the form submission route (formsubmit:form). This is so the POST data goes to the correct view that processes the form submission.
Here's the modified code.

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms 

# Create your views here.

orders_stock = ['headphones', 'earbuds', 'diy tools']



class NewOrder(forms.Form):
    get_order = forms.CharField(label='Your order', max_length=50)


def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = NewOrder(request.POST)
        if item.is_valid():
            get_order = item.cleaned_data['get_order']
            orders_stock.append(get_order)
            
            # Redirect to the 'order' view after successful submission
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('formsubmit:order'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'form/form.html', {
                'items': orders_stock
            })

    return render(request, 'form/form.html', {
        'form': NewOrder()
    })


def order(request):
    return render(request, 'form/orders.html', {
        'items': orders_stock,
    })


form.html

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Form submission</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'formsubmit:form' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I hope this will help you a little.

Thank you so much, that's working!

glad to hear that it was helpful.
